# Как сделать TextView выше ImageView?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Каким образом можно расположит картинку ниже текста программно?
Вот xml-код:.

```
<ScrollView...>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="45px"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
           />
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/foto1"
        android:src="@mipmap/foto"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Вот java-код:

```
public class Text extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.textfile);
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        text.setText("Просто текст")
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zvezda);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.foto);
```

Проблема в том что картинка наползает на текст, а нужно чтобы она была ниже текста. Как можно реализовать это или что необходимо еще добавить?

Answer (score 2):

Просто поместите картинку внутрь `LinearLayout`, сразу за `TextView`

```
<ScrollView...>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="45px"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
           <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/foto1"
            android:src="@mipmap/foto"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```